# variable equal to a numeric day of the month

Tags: javascript

I am trying to get this to work for each numeric day of the month.  It works without the ||.  Any ideas how to make it work with the ||?

```
<script>
        var now = new Date();
        var day = ("0" + now.getDate()).slice(-2);
        var month = ("0" + (now.getMonth() + 1)).slice(-2);
        var today = (month) + "-" + (day) + "-" + now.getFullYear();
        var d = new Date();
        var n = d.getDate();
        if ((day == 13) || 
        (day == 16) ||
        (day == 19) ||
        (day == 22)) {
            document.getElementById("shift").innerHTML="A SHIFT" + " " + today;
        }
        else if ((day == 14) || 
        (day == 17) || 
        (day == 20) ||
        (day == 23)) {
            document.getElementById("shift").innerHTML="B SHIFT" + " " + today;
        }
        else ((day == 15) || 
        (day == 18) || 
        (day == 21) ||
        (day == 24)) {
            document.getElementById("shift").innerHTML="C SHIFT" + " " + today;
        }
</script>
```

Comment: I'm not quite sure what you mean by it works without the ||. Could you provide a working example? Also `"A SHIFT" + " " + today` can just be shortened to `"A SHIFT " + today`

Comment: For simple typographical errors like this the best way to catch them is by viewing the console logs in your JS interpreter. All modern browsers have a built in JS console that you can use for debugging and for viewing errors thrown by your code.

Answer (score 0):

Your code won't produce any output because there is a syntax error. Fixing that seems to address your issue—[jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/rLa2xec3/).

You can't follow an `else` with a conditional. That only works if you say `else if`.

```
else ((day == 15) || 
        (day == 18) || 
        (day == 21) ||
        (day == 24)) {
```

produces `Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token {`, or something similar (depending on your browser).

Correct code:

```
var now = new Date();
var day = ("0" + now.getDate()).slice(-2);
var month = ("0" + (now.getMonth() + 1)).slice(-2);
var today = (month) + "-" + (day) + "-" + now.getFullYear();
var d = new Date();
var n = d.getDate();

if ((day == 13) || (day == 16) || (day == 19) || (day == 22)) {
    document.getElementById("shift").innerHTML = "A SHIFT " + today;
} else if ((day == 14) || (day == 17) || (day == 20) || (day == 23)) {
    document.getElementById("shift").innerHTML = "B SHIFT " + today;
} else if ((day == 15) || (day == 18) || (day == 21) || (day == 24)) {
    document.getElementById("shift").innerHTML = "C SHIFT " + today;
}
```

Comment: @user1913733 You can also make your if cases simpler by using an array of dates as in [this jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/rLa2xec3/2/)—`[13,16,19,22].indexOf(day) > -1`. Or using a `switch` statement as in [this other jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/rLa2xec3/3/). Note the `day = +day;` for making the value an int instead of a string.

Answer (score 0):

Alternatively, you can refactor the whole solution and make the objective more readable

```
<script language="javascript" type="text/javascript">
  // Get todays date and split it into dd, yyyy, mm components
  var now = new Date();
  var yyyy = now.getFullYear().toString();
  var mm = (now.getMonth()+1).toString();
  var dd  = now.getDate().toString();

  // Build padded_date in the format mm-dd-yyyy
  var padded_date = (mm[1]?mm:"0"+mm[0]) + '-' + (dd[1]?dd:"0"+dd[0]) + '-' + yyyy;
  alert(padded_date);

  // Determine the only variable that changes in your latter code
  var shift_alphabet;
  switch (parseInt(dd)) {
    case 13:
    case 16:
    case 19:
    case 22:  shift_alphabet = 'A';
              break;
    case 14:
    case 17:
    case 20:
    case 23:  shift_alphabet = 'B';
              break;
    case 15:
    case 18:
    case 21:
    case 24:  shift_alphabet = 'C';
              break;
    default:  shift_alphabet = 'A' // Assumption
              break;
  }

  // Using alerts because I don't have the HTML stuff
  alert(shift_alphabet);
  // Append shift alphabet to your output
  // document.getElementById("shift").innerHTML= shift_alphabet + " SHIFT" + " " + padded_date;
```

Comment: Nice job refactoring and getting rid of the repetitive pieces. One thing to look out for though is the fact that `dd` is a string. So it won't match your cases unless you convert it to an int. You can simply make it `switch (+dd)`, and then it will alert the correct value (B in my case, on 8/14).

Comment: Good spot. parseInt() to the rescue :)